# How to return a value after making the request with OAuth2Request?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.auth

I'm trying to return the value of an object but it returns null, however it returns a value in the request.

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Auth;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace RegistroAgil_Couchbase.Droid
{
    public class UserInfoRepository
    {
        public OAuthUserInfo Get()
        {
            var mainActivity = Forms.Context as MainActivity;
            var accounts = AccountStore.Create(mainActivity).FindAccountsForService("Facebook");
            var enumerable = accounts as IList<Account> ?? accounts.ToList();
            var account = enumerable.FirstOrDefault () == null ? null : enumerable.First ();

            if (account == null) {
                return null;
            } else {
                var request = new OAuth2Request ("GET", new Uri ("https://graph.facebook.com/me"), null, account);

                JObject obj = new JObject ();

                request.GetResponseAsync ().ContinueWith (t => {
                    if (t.IsFaulted)
                        Console.WriteLine ("Error: " + t.Exception.InnerException.Message);
                    else {
                        obj = JObject.Parse (t.Result.GetResponseText ());

                        Console.WriteLine(obj["name"]); // <-- Here returns a value.
                    }
                });

                return new OAuthUserInfo {
                    AuthName = (string)obj ["name"] // <-- Returns null.
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I’d really appreciate any help anyone can provide. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why you don´t use the Facebook SDK instead of manual authenticate the user ?

Comment: Well, basically I want to implement it with Twitter or any other type of account later. And also to experiment with this component, only that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.

```
var waitEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
```

before line

```
request.GetResponseAsync ().ContinueWith (t => {
```

2.

```
waitEvent.Set();
```

after

```
obj = JObject.Parse (t.Result.GetResponseText ());
```

3.

```
waitEvent.WaitOne();
```

before

```
return new OAuthUserInfo {
```

Or

method should be

```
public async Task<OAuthUserInfo> Get()
```

and call to request

```
var object = await request.GetResponseAsync ();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and detailed answer. I modified my code with your answer, and works like charm. Thanks a lot. :D

Comment: It would have looked a lot cleaner if you copied the OP source code, made modifications to it and pointed them out with comments.